# Why does Chrome add two tabs at the end of my xlsx file and by doing so, is corrupting the files?

Tags: php, excel, google-chrome, yii2

I am developing an app with yii2 and I am using PhpSpreadsheet to generate (Excel)  `.xlsx` files. When I download a generated `.xlsx` file with Chrome, I can not open it with Excel (2019), since Excel prompts that the file is corrupted, offers to repair it but fails.

First i suspected something wrong with the generator or the download process, but I've tested the download with Firefox, Edge and Filezilla - everything works as expected.

A comparison of the downloaded files in hex shows just one minor difference: At the end of the .xlsx file downloaded with other Browsers, I see

```
786d 6c2e 7265 6c73 504b 0506 0000 0000
0b00 0b00 d102 0000 671d 0000 0000
```

but the Chrome-Download shows

```
786d 6c2e 7265 6c73 504b 0506 0000 0000
0b00 0b00 d102 0000 671d 0000 0000 0909
```

I have no idea where these extra 09's are coming from. Those are two tabs (09) chrome is adding and thus corrupting the file. OpenOffice's Calc is able to read it but Excel just can't open it.

So, again, my question is: Why is Chrome seemingly adding two tabs to the end of my file? And what can I do to prevent this?

**Update:**
I have narrowed the problem down to "logged in with Chrome" (logged in into the yii-application, not Chrome!). Meaning: I can download and open the file with Firefox and Edge, logged in or not logged in **and** it works with Chrome when I am **not** logged in. I would blame the login but then this should also corrupt the file / add 2 extra 09's when I download it with Firefox or Edge...

**Update 2:**
I have installed the new Edge Version 78.0.276.17 (Official build) beta (64-bit) that's based on the Chromium Engine: **Same Problem!** Logged in: File corrupt. Not logged in: File works!

**Update 3:**
I've tested a random file.txt that i uploaded via FTP and there are 2 tabs added to the end of the file, when i download it via the yii's sendFile-Method:

```
public function actionTest(){
   Yii::$app->response->sendFile('test.txt')->send();
   return true;
}
```

If I download the file by directly linking to it, it's perfectly fine. Again it's a combination of Chromium, being logged in and the sendFile-method, it seems.

Comment: are you saying these tabs are included in the `.xlsx` file when you download it through chrome?  and is it any file generated with the extension `.xlsx` or just for any specific listing or content in the `.xlsx` file?

Comment: No, I am saying that Chrome is changing the file and adding those tabs. (Or is this what you meant?) It's for any ```.xlsx``` file I a) generate on the server b) save on the server and then c) download with Chrome. The content does not seem to matter / I have added and deleted entries in the table to change the file(size) but the result is always the same: When I download it with Chrome, there are two tabs at the end of the file added.

Comment: is there any way that you could share a link where i can click & download the file via my chrome browser and see if it replicates?

Comment: Have you tried starting chrome [without extensions](https://www.techsupportall.com/start-google-chrome-without-extensions/)?

Comment: @MichalHynčica Yes, I have tried that. I edited my question, since I've discovered that the problem can be narrowed down to "logged in with Chrome". When I am NOT logged in with Chrome, the file works.

Comment: And by "logged in" do you mean into your website or into you google account in chrome?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I've updated my question. The problem with the corrupted file only occurs when I am logged in. But just with Chrome. With raises even more questions.

Comment: @MichalHynčica I mean the website itself. I have recorded a short video where I download the file logged in, log out and then call the download-action again (please ignore the watermark): https://youtu.be/NZdywhTw6NE

Comment: Maybe it's not that chrome is adding them but that firefox/edge are removing them. Have you tried to check Content-Length header in response and compare it to the size of downloaded file?

Comment: havent faced any such issue in the past, seems odd but i would go for what @MichalHynčica has said that you must compare the content-length header in response in both the scenarios, still i suspect that the issue is on the browser, i recently implemented a feature for the application similar to yours where we filter out leads from 2 diff campaigns based on some constraints and it provides you the download link of the xlsx file i had `Chrome Version 77.0.3865.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and it works correctly, i upvoted your question for the same reason that i was blank about whats the reason

Comment: just check one thing if there is no content in the file, its just empty. does it still corrupt the file when you download it?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I've just tested this with a txt file, see updated question. Same behaviour. I'll see if I can find out anything on yii's github support.

Comment: My hypothesis is that you have those tabs somewhere in file with class that is used only for logged in users. Probably at the start/end of file outside of <?php ?> tags. The sendFile() method sets Content-Length based on the actual size of file so those tabs are not included in Content-Length. Firefox and older Edge probably throws away anything after the Content-Length but Chrome and the beta Edge saves all recieved data.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam The content-length in the response header is exactly the same. See https://imgur.com/Vw6NSGz

Comment: @MichalHynčica I think you are right. I've just copied the test.txt file to another yii project and tested the download with the exact same code without any problems o.O ... Frack me .... I will investigate further and update my Question as soon as I have figured out anything new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**And the solution is:**

My **i8n translations file** `.../frontend/languages/de-DE/app.php` had two tabs in front of `<?php`, as suggested by @MichalHynčica! Removing those two tabs resulted in perfectly fine downloaded files.

Edit: In addition to this, the Chromium engine seems to ignore the content-length defined in the HTTP header and the actual content length of the downloaded file.

Thank you and good night.