# Broken xlsx file in attachment sent by swiftmailer smtp Yii2

Tags: php, email, yii2, attachment, swiftmailer

I am sending an email with an attachment using Yii2 and Swiftmailer.
When I try to open a file in my Google account, Google writes that the file is damaged. I tried to download the file and open it, but my excel also told me that the file is damaged.

BUT, I tried to open the file before sending, and it opens perfectly. I also tried to send the file through my email client and then the file also opens up nicely.

I tried using different SMTP servers, nothing changes.

What could be the problem?

I enclose the code.

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'XXX',
            'username' => 'XXX',
            'password' => 'XXX',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
        ],
    ],
```

and

```
$emailManager = new EmailManager();
$mailer = $emailManager->actionSendfile($address, $filename, $subject, [
    'contentType' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
]);
```

and

```
public function actionSendfile($to, $filePathArray, $subject, $options = [])
{
    $send = Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom(['noreply@example.com'])
        ->setTo($to)
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->setHtmlBody("Some text");

        if(is_array($filePathArray)){
            foreach($filePathArray as $value){
                $send->attach($value, $options);
            }
        } else {
            $send->attach($filePathArray, $options);
        }


        return $send->send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any translation files in you yii application?

I had a similar problem where i directly downloaded XLSX files had two additional tabs at the end of the file, which corrupted it. The tabs came from my translation file.

Try comparing the damaged file you get via mail with the file that works in hex to find differences.

See this for more info: [Why does Chrome add two tabs at the end of my xlsx file and by doing so, is corrupting the files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382553/why-does-chrome-add-two-tabs-at-the-end-of-my-xlsx-file-and-by-doing-so-is-corr/58398001#58398001)

(You could also try opening the XLSX file with OpenOffice Calc, it's not as picky as Excel and tends to open "damaged" files.)